# ¿Aceleración y velocidad a un personaje?

Tags: c++, arduino

**Introducción:**

Estoy haciendo un juego y el personaje principal no tiene aceleración, solo avanza 2 pixeles por Frame, lo cual se ve algo mal y monótono.

El juego se está haciendo en C++ para el Arduboy, un pequeño aparato con la apariencia de los antiguos Gameboys programable con Arduino y una pequeña pantalla monocromática de 128x64 pixeles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Pregunta:**

¿Cual es el procedimiento para hacer aceleración en mi personaje?

[GitHub](https://github.com/J053Fabi0/Pixel_Guy_Arduboy_1.0)

Comment: Estas usando algún motor de video juegos?

Comment: No, es un Juego para el Arduboy, un pequeño Arduino con una pantalla de 128 x 68 pixeles

Comment: Como consejo deberías publicar el lenguaje en especifico en el que deseas, aunque la lógica sea igual es mejor que lo entiendas aplicado a lo que haces, y pues tmb un pedazo del codigo, para que el que te ayude se le haga mas facil y entienda que deseas hacer

Comment: Editada, gracias por el consejo :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para dotar de aceleración basta con mantener dos variables, una con la posición del personaje y otra con su velocidad y una constante, su aceleración.

Algoritmo (pseudo-C):

```
#define ACELERACION 0.1
#define VELOCIDAD_MAX 2
float vel = 0, pos = 0;

/* Inicio del bucle, lo anterior eran sólo definiciones */
if ( botón == derecha ) {
  /* Aceleramos a la derecha (o frenamos inercia a la izquierda) */
  vel += ACELERACION;
  /* Controlamos que no podamos avanzar más rápido del límite */
  if (vel > VELOCIDAD_MAX) {
    vel = VELOCIDAD_MAX;
  }
} else if (boton = izquierda) {
  /* Aceleramos a la izquierda (o frenamos inercia a la derecha) */
  vel -= ACELERACION;
  /* Controlamos que no podamos avanzar más rápido del límite */
  if (vel < -VELOCIDAD_MAX) {
    vel = -VELOCIDAD_MAX;
  }
} else {
  /* Si estamos en cero o sólo queda un paso para parar, paramos.
    también podría ser un simple "if (vel == 0) {" */
  if (abs(vel) < ACELERACION) {
    vel = 0;
  } else if (vel > 0) {
    /* No paramos inmediatamente, vamos decelerando */
    vel -= ACELERACION;
  } else {
    vel += ACELERACION;
  }
}
/* Fin de las comprobaciones, actualizamos la posición */
pos += vel;
```

La posición es un double, quizá debieras pasarlo a entero si es necesario, o quizá trabajar sólo con enteros de coma fija, lo que prefieras.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Que significa abs(vel)?

Comment: Es el [valor absoluto](https://linux.die.net/man/3/abs) de un número, provoca una conversión de `float` a `int`, por lo que quizá te interese cambiarlo por la versión de [coma flotante `fabsf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fabsf) dependiendo del caso.

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó